# Why I'm getting maximum update depth exceeded error when setting data to context (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React project I wanted to share the currency, which selected by the user, within the components using a context. Context functionality works fine, however, there is a small issue that I want to fix. It is setting default currency to the context. So, when the web is started at the very beginning there will be a default currency set to the context, which is going to come from the selection that is provided from the endpoint. I used an if-statement as shown in CurrencySelector.js but I was getting that error "Maximum Update Depth Exceeded." I provided my code for the context and currency selection component.

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";

const CurrencyContext = createContext();

class CurrencyContextProvider extends Component {
  state = { selectedCurrency: "uuu" };
  setCurrency = (c) => {
    this.setState({ selectedCurrency: c });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <CurrencyContext.Provider
        value={{ ...this.state, setCurrency: this.setCurrency }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </CurrencyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

class CurrencySelector extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("CurrencySelector constructor");
    this.state = { currencies: [] };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let currencies = (await this.getCurrencies()).data
      .currencies;
    this.setState({ currencies: currencies });
  }

  async getCurrencies() {
    return await fetchAnyQuery(`query{ currencies }`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CurrencyContext.Consumer>
        {(currencyContext) => {
          const {
            selectedCurrency,
            setCurrency,
          } = currencyContext;
          return (
            <select
              name="currency-selector"
              onChange={(event) => {
                setCurrency(event.target.value);
              }}
            >
              {this.state.currencies.map((currency, index) => {
                //When I wrote this if-statement I got the error
                if (index == 0) {
                  setCurrency(currency);
                }
                return (
                  <option value={currency}>{currency}</option>
                );
              })}
            </select>
          );
        }}
      </CurrencyContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @akx There is no need to re-format the code. The functionality of the context works fine, I just want to fix the error that I get. Check the comment in CurrencySelector.js

Comment: I reformatted it for readability, so it's easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//When I wrote this if-statement I got the error
if (index == 0) {
  setCurrency(currency);
}
```

Yes – you would get an error, since you're mutating state *during render*, which is expressly forbidden. (This isn't specific to using a context.)

You have a couple options I can think of:

- move the currency loading to the context provider, and have the context provider set the default currency once it's loaded the currencies
- "fake" having a default currency set if one hasn't been set (but that will get hairy really quickly)

Here's an example of the first option.

See how `getCurrencies()` has been hoisted up to the `componentDidMount()` of the provider.

A bit of extra care will need to be applied, since it might be that the currencies haven't been loaded yet; see how we only render "Loading..." for that time.

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";

const CurrencyContext = createContext();

// Fake fetcher function that just takes a bit of time.
function fetchAnyQuery() {
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve({ data: { currencies: ["a", "b", "c"] } }), 1000)
  );
}

class CurrencyContextProvider extends Component {
  state = { selectedCurrency: "uuu", currencies: undefined };
  setCurrency = (c) => {
    this.setState({ selectedCurrency: c });
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const currencies = (await this.getCurrencies()).data.currencies;

    this.setState(({ selectedCurrency }) => {
      if (!currencies.includes(selectedCurrency)) {
        // If the selected currency is invalid, reset it to the first one
        selectedCurrency = currencies[0];
      }
      return { currencies, selectedCurrency };
    });
  }

  async getCurrencies() {
    return await fetchAnyQuery(`query{ currencies }`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CurrencyContext.Provider
        value={{ ...this.state, setCurrency: this.setCurrency }}
      >
        {this.state.currencies ? this.props.children : <>Loading...</>}
      </CurrencyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

class CurrencySelector extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <CurrencyContext.Consumer>
        {(currencyContext) => {
          const { selectedCurrency, currencies, setCurrency } = currencyContext;
          return (
            <div>
              <select
                name="currency-selector"
                value={selectedCurrency}
                onChange={(event) => {
                  setCurrency(event.target.value);
                }}
              >
                {currencies.map((currency) => (
                  <option value={currency} key={currency}>
                    {currency}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
              <br />
              Selected: {selectedCurrency}
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </CurrencyContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <CurrencyContextProvider>
      <CurrencySelector />
    </CurrencyContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: How would I do the first one. Could you please give a simple example?

Comment: @asemshaat Sure. See my edit.